# Растягивание текстуры по центру

Tags: objective-c, xcode, iphone, spritekit

Есть текстура/node с закругленными краями, и необходимо менять ее ширину и высоту, но при этом что бы углы оставались такие какие есть, т.е. растягивать текстуру/node по центру, не трогая края. 
Был легкий способ реализации этого, но ни как не могу его найти.

[image: a busy cat]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужен [resizableImageWithCapInsets:](http://resizableImageWithCapInsets:)

Использовать примерно так:

```
UIImage *myImage = [someImage resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(1, 1, 1, 1)];
```

создаст новый UIImage на основании данного, с постоянным одним пикселем с каждой стороны и растянутым центром.

Comment: Так же еще нашел под SpriteKit: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Sprites/Sprites.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043-CH9-SW10